# issue with kafka source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I will appreciate it if someone can help me figure out why my kafka consumer is displaying its schema "fields" as shown below, instead of to display the data type and the column names as should be.

```
confirmuserreg    |   schema: {
confirmuserreg    |     type: 'struct',
confirmuserreg    |     fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
confirmuserreg    |     optional: false,
confirmuserreg    |     name: 'smartdevdbserver1.signup_db.users.Envelope'
confirmuserreg    |   },
confirmuserreg    |   payload: {
confirmuserreg    |     before: null,
confirmuserreg    |     after: {
confirmuserreg    |       id: 44,
confirmuserreg    |       email: 'testing13@firstclicklimited.com',
confirmuserreg    |       password: '$2a$10$lJ5ILqdiJMXoJhHBOLmFeOAF3gppc9ZNgPrzTRnzDU18kX4lxu19C',
confirmuserreg    |       User_status: 'INACTIVE',
confirmuserreg    |       auth_token: null
confirmuserreg    |     },
confirmuserreg    |     source: {
confirmuserreg    |       version: '1.9.5.Final',
confirmuserreg    |       connector: 'mysql',
confirmuserreg    |       name: 'smartdevdbserver1',
confirmuserreg    |       ts_ms: 1666790831000,
confirmuserreg    |       snapshot: 'false',
confirmuserreg    |       db: 'signup_db',
confirmuserreg    |       sequence: null,
confirmuserreg    |       table: 'users',
confirmuserreg    |       server_id: 1,
confirmuserreg    |       gtid: '4e390d46-53b4-11ed-b7c4-0242ac140003:33',
confirmuserreg    |       file: 'binlog.000008',
confirmuserreg    |       pos: 487,
confirmuserreg    |       row: 0,
confirmuserreg    |       thread: 41,
confirmuserreg    |       query: null
confirmuserreg    |     },
confirmuserreg    |     op: 'c',
confirmuserreg    |     ts_ms: 1666790832054,
confirmuserreg    |     transaction: null
confirmuserreg    |   }
```

It should be something like this instead:

```
{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "Name"}, {"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "company"}],"optional": false,"name": "Person"},"payload": {"Name": "deepak","company": "BT"}}
```

This is my connector config:

```
{
  "name": "smartdevsignupconnector112",  
  "config": {  
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",  
    "database.hostname": "mysql1",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "clusterAdmin",
    "database.password": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "database.server.id": "184055",  
    "database.server.name": "smartdevdbserver1",  
    "database.include.list": "signup_db",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka1:9092",  
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.smartdevdbserver1",
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "table.whitelist": "signup_db.users",
    "column.blacklist": "signup_db.users.fullName, signup_db.users.address, signup_db.users.phoneNo, signup_db.users.gender, signup_db.users.userRole, signup_db.users.reason_for_inactive, signup_db.users.firstvisit, signup_db.users.last_changed_PW, signup_db.users.regDate",
    "snapshot.mode": "when_needed"
  }
}
```

I expect record from 5 columns (email, password, User_status, auth_token, including the primary key) to be displayed and below is the table schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fullName` varchar(66),
  `address` varchar(77),
  `phoneNo` varchar(16),
  `gender` varchar(6),
  `userRole` enum('visitor','student','Admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'visitor',
  `User_status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INACTIVE',
  `reason_for_inactive` enum('visitor','TERMINATED','SUSPENDED_FOR_VIOLATION') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'visitor',
  `firstvisit` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_changed_PW` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `regDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `auth_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should be something like this instead

Debezium has its own event format, so no, it shouldn't look like that.

---

Seems your `confirmuserreg` service is a Javascript application, and you are simply having `[Object]` as the default `console.log()` output for deeply nested JS objects.

If you don't care about the Debezium metdata, then [flatten the event](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html). That way, KSQL will read the `payload.after` field and be able to extract the fields within.

Comment: yes confirmuserreg service is a nodejs service and perhaps as you hinted, it must be the reason why it behaves like that. So what i did to be sure that the fields record are what it should was to use kafkacat consumer utility to monitor the topic - and i found that that the field displayed the way it should be. But now that my doubt is cleared leads me to the original issue i was having which led me to asking this question which i have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74222749/confluent-kafka-sink-connector-error-java-sql-sqlexception-field-email-doesn