# Confluent kafka sink connector error: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'email' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to take data from kafka topic and then insert it to a mysql database table. The topic (smartdevdbserver1.signup_db.users) is derived from another mysql database table column called users and is populated using a debezium CDC mysql source connector.
I will be grateful if someone can help me figure out why the sink connector is throwing the below error:

```
connect           | java.sql.SQLException: Field 'email' doesn't have a default value
connect           | 
connect           |     at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:93)
connect           |     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)
connect           |     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)
connect           |     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)
connect           |     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)
connect           |     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
connect           |     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
connect           |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
connect           |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
connect           |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
connect           |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
connect           |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
connect           | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'email' doesn't have a default value       
connect           | java.sql.SQLException: Field 'email' doesn't have a default value
```

The schema and payload of kafka topic looks like this:

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"email"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"password"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"ACTIVE,INACTIVE"},"default":"INACTIVE","field":"User_status"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"auth_token"}],"optional":false,"name":"smartdevdbserver1.signup_db.users.Value"},"payload":{"id":6,"email":"testing6@firstclicklimited.com","password":"$2a$10$PRGfCpjCCKqSKSf89m5M6uSRWzjlZTG7RuuJgR5MrVY.nh0BKA7Nq","User_status":"INACTIVE","auth_token":null}}
```

Below is the kafka sink connector config:

```
{
    "name": "resetpassword-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "topics": "smartdevdbserver1.signup_db.users",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://RPWD_mysql:3306/rpwd_db?user=rpwd_user&password=*xxxxxxxx*",
        "fields.whitelist": "rpwd_db.users.email,rpwd_db.users.password,rpwd_db.users.User_status,rpwd_db.users.auth_token",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "table.name.format": "rpwd_db.users",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
    }
}
```

The table schema where data is to be inserted:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `User_status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INACTIVE',
  `auth_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I tried to use auto.create so that the sink connector can create its own table (just so i see if the error will go away) but the table it created had just one field (and that's the primary key field: id), and of course, there was no error. So i am guessing that the sink connector sees every other field (perhaps) as a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar happened to me. Have you tried removing the schema and table from **fields.whitelist** property?

```
"fields.whitelist": "email,password,User_status,auth_token"
```